# Accessing browser history in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, http-headers, browser-history

If I am at site abc.com and I go to my site def.com which hosts a silverlight app.  How can I find out which domain I just came from within my silverlight app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You will have to use Javascript for that and even then you won't be able to see from which site the user came, you can just go back to the previous page.

You can do it on the server side by checking the web server logs.

Comment: You only get the referring URL if the site was visited via a link. If you visit via a link you can also get the UrlReferrer via the hosting page and pass into Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you got to your site via a link (this does not work if you simply typed in your website address), your hosting ASPX page on def.com will receive a referring URL.

You then just need to pass it into the Silverlight application via the InitParams setting of the Silverlight control.

See the [HttpRequest.UrlReferrer Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [this example](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2010/07/how-to-pass-values-to-silverlight.html) on how to pass the property to Silverlight.